# How do I perform xargs grep on grep output that has spaces?

Tags: shell, grep, find, quoting, xargs

I'm searching for files based on a regular expression, and then I'm trying to search those files for content. So, for example, I have something like

```
#Find all C++ files that match a certain pattern and then search them
find . -name "*.cpp" | grep "<name regex>" | xargs grep "<content regex>"
```

The problem I'm running into is that some of the paths have spaces in them, which confuses `xargs`. I know that if I was just using `find`, I could use the `-print0` argument (along with the `-0` argument on `xargs`) to keep xargs from treating spaces as delimiters. Is there something similar with `grep`?

Or am I approaching this problem in the wrong way entirely? Naively, `find` to `grep` to `xargs grep` makes sense to me, but I'm open to other approaches that yield the same results.

Comment: you can position arguments with `xargs` by using `-i` parameter, a la `cat sample.txt | grep "pat t ern" | xargs -i grep "{}"` -- the curly braces tell it where to position the argument. The manual tells me that `-i` is deprecated in favor of `-I` so maybe worth taking a look at that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this perhaps (if gnu grep).

```
grep -r 'content pattern' --include==*.cpp
```

man grep

> --include=GLOB Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude)

Also see the options for null delimiters.

> -Z, --null  Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.  For example, grep  -lZ  outputs  a  zero  byte after each file name instead of the usual newline.  This option makes the output unambiguous, even in the presence of file names containing unusual characters like newlines.  This option can be used with commands  like  find  -print0, perl -0, sort -z, and xargs -0 to process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.
>
> -z, --null-data Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like  the  -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

Comment: Note that `grep -r include='*.cpp'` is a shell glob - and so is feature-aligned w/ `find . -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -e 'content_pattern' -- {} \;` not w/ `find . -name '*.cpp' | grep 'name_pattern' | xargs grep 'content_pattern'`

Answer (score 5):

If you have to jump through a lot of hoops, then the efficiency of xargs is lost anyway. Here is one crude work around:

```
find . -iname "*.cpp" | grep "<pattern>" | while read -r x; do grep exa "$x"; done
```

Every time I run into problems with spaces in file names, the answer is double quotes on a variable.

Comment: This runs the loop's inner grep uniquely for each line found by the outer grep. That's a lot of overhead.

Comment: As usual, beware if e.g. some file names have any carriage return inside ([How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), `grep -Z`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` to do all the filename filtering.  Rather than

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | grep "foo" | xargs grep …
```

do

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -name "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep …
```

If you want to do something slightly more complicated, like

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | egrep "foo|bar" | xargs grep …
```

you can do

```
find . -name "*.cpp" "(" -name "*foo*" -o -name "*bar*" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 grep …
```

Note that these should work even for files with *newlines* in their names.

And, if you need the power of full-blown regular expressions,
you can use `-regex`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work even without GNU tools:

```
#Find all C++ files that match a certain pattern and then search them
find . -name "*.cpp"  | grep "<name regex>" | perl -pe 's/\n/\0/' \
  | xargs -0 grep "<content regex>"
```

The `perl` call replaces line breaks with null characters, which will allow `xargs -0` to interpret the input on a per-line basis rather than a per-whitespace basis.

Using GNU, you can remove the `perl` call and change `xargs -0 …` to `xargs -d "\n" …`

Don't have `perl` or GNU? Try `awk '{printf "%s%c", $0, 0}'` instead.

Comment: This may not do the right thing if some of the file names include newlines (a rather unusual occurrence, for sure, but not impossible).

Comment: @dhag has a valid point regarding `xargs -d "\n"`.  That's a *very* unusual occurrence, but if you don't have control of the data and are worried about it being a security risk, be careful about output expectations.